# Why do we have to re-interrupt Thread in catch?

Tags: java, multithreading

It seems like a Thread is loosing the interrupted state after throwing InterruptedException.
But I can't find any info about this.

- Where can I see the state of a thread after it was interrupted?
- Why should I care about the state of a gone thread, if I logged it.?

I do appreciate your answers a lot!

```
  public void run () {
    try {
      while (true) { 
       // do stuff   
   }  
  }catch (InterruptedException e) 
{      LOGGER.log(Level.WARN, "Interrupted!", e); 
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();    // Restoring the state
}
  }
```

Comment: I don't really understand your questions. If you decide to interrupt a thread then theres a reason for that. You should know what you're supposed to do in that situation. And throwing `InterruptedException` doesn't clear the interrupted state. It is cleared by `Thread.interrupted()` [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted())

Comment: `It seems like a Thread is loosing the interrupted state after throwing InterruptedException.` As far as I know this is correct.